# Polynomial Diophantine Equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

So in general how does one decide if:
$$ a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 ... a_{n_1}x^{n_1} = b_1y + b_2y^2 ... + b_{n_2}y^{n_k}$$

Has solutions for integers $x,y$ given real numbers $a_0, a_1. .. a_{n_1}, b_1 , b_2 ... b_{n_2}$

I noticed:
In general deciding

$$ a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 ... a_{n_1}x^{n_1} = b_0y $$

Is really a matter of deciding if there exists integers $x$ such that:

$$a_1x + a_2x^2 ... a_{n_1}x^{n_1} \equiv -a_0 \mod b_0$$

Thus my question can also be rephrased as. What sort of abstract machinery (a generalization of modular arithmetic can be created) to decide for problems of the variety given earlier?

Comment: It is widely believed (but not yet proved) that if we restrict your coefficients to integers, there is a decision procedure. There is a lot of machinery available, mainly Diophantine approximations. With (recursive) reals, I have not seen the question considered. My guess is that there is no decision procedure.

Comment: @Andre Nichols, by 'recursive reals' do you mean to differentiate between numbers like $ \pi$ and $e$ from say $2^{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}}$ the latter being generated from some finite combination of recursive arithmetic operations on the integers and the former only being generated through the use of limits?

Comment: The numbers $\pi$ and $e$ are recursive reals, roughly speaking because there is an algorithm for computing them to arbitrary precision.

Comment: What's an example of a number that is not a recursive real?

Comment: One can construct one by looking at one of the usual non-recursive sets, say one coming out of the Halting Problem, and letting $x$ have $n$-th digit $1$ if $n$ is in the set, and $2$ if $n$ is not in the set. But *existence* is simpler. There are only countably many algorithms, so countably many recursive reals, and there are uncountably many reals. so almost all reals are non-recursive.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn some stuff on [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma), which is quite strong in such problems.